# Is it ture that any zonoid (not a trivial zonotope), must be a affine image of a unit ball (l2)?

Tags: convex-geometry, polyhedra, ellipsoids

I am trying to find some literature discussing zonoid in 3-dimensional space. And a seemly simple question that I am considered specifically is what are those non-trivial (not being a zonohedron) zonoid are in 3d?

All ellipsoids seems to be zonoid in 3d, but is it ture that this is the only familarly of non-trivial zonoid in 3d? If so, is there an elegant way of proving that? if not, is there a counter-example? or any way to construct more different zonoid?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.